# How i change a logo size inside an a cicrcle

Tags: html, css

How i change the logo size inside the circle. They look like this[image]
but i want this size[image]

HTML

```
            <div class="column" span="1">
              <div class="performance__disc">
                <div class="icon__speedometer"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.performance__disc{
    background-color:   rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-top: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: #71c4dd;
    
   [class^="icon__"]{
       position: absolute;
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       top: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `font-size` on `[class^="icon__"]`?

Comment: No:)), it's works